# JS требуется ответ ДА или НЕТ

Tags: javascript

Вот код

```
<style type="text/css">
      #hid {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: #FF0000;
        opacity: 0;
        position: fixed;
      }
      body {
        height: 1500px;
      }
    </style>
<body>
    <div id="hid"></div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      var element = $("#hid"), display;
      $(window).scroll(function () {
        display = $(this).scrollTop() >= 20;
        display != element.css('opacity') && element.stop().animate({ 'opacity': display }, 500);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Он рабочий. Я собираюсь вставить его в конкретно блок на страницу. Собственно, я далека от этого и не могу понять, мне нужно вставить ВЕСЬ код как он выглядит здесь, 
или

```
/*выносится в css*/
#hid {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #FF0000;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
  }
/*, а это*/
  <div id="hid"></div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      var element = $("#hid"), display;
      $(window).scroll(function () {
        display = $(this).scrollTop() >= 20;
        display != element.css('opacity') && element.stop().animate({ 'opacity': display }, 500);
      });
    });
  </script>
```

уже как раз и должно быть в нужном блоке?

Потому что второй вариант косячно работает. Такие дела.

Да, нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `#hid {...` – в подлинкованный css или просто тег `<style>` в голове (`<head>`) страницы;
2. `<div id="hid"></div>` в нужное место на странице;
3. `<script>...` – в самом конце страницы, перед `</body>`

Глючить может из-за того, например, что на странице уже где-то загружается jQuery.

Comment: А ваш ответ это "да" или "нет"? :)

Comment: оба варианта при конвертации в Boolean приводятся в true : )

Comment: Спасибо Sergiks'у. Огромное.